# How to select 10 rows below the result returned by the SQL query?

Tags: sql

Here is the SQL table:

```
KEY | NAME    | VALUE  
---------------------
13b | Jeffrey | 23.5  
F48 | Jonas   | 18.2  
2G8 | Debby   | 21.1
```

Now, if I type:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM table  
 WHERE VALUE = 23.5
```

I will get the first row.

What I need to accomplish is to get the first and the next two rows below. Is there a way to do it?

Columns are not sorted and WHERE condition doesn't participate in the selection of the rows, except for the first one. I just need the two additional rows below the returned one - the ones that were entered after the one which has been returned by the SELECT query.

Comment: It seems dangerous to assume that unsorted rows will be in a particular order in the database.

Comment: So any additional two rows can be returned?  The data implies that you want rows less than or equal to the stated value.

Comment: Going off what you have here is the equivalent of saying: I want rows where value = 23.5 and 10 random rows.

Comment: Is `KEY` lexicographically ascending, such that a row inserted temporally after another (which seems to be what you want) has a higher `KEY`?  A few answers below assume "yes."  Is `VALUE` unique?  A few answers below assume "yes."

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer and the comments. Your clarification have been very helpful. I understand now that I must have the data sorted by some colum in order to be able to achieve what I needed. AdaTheDev has provided the clearest and the most straight forward explanation below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You **need** to define an order to the results to do this. There is no guaranteed order to the data otherwise.
If by "the next 2 rows after" you mean "the next 2 records that were inserted into the table AFTER that particular row", you will need to use an auto incrementing field or a "date create" timestamp field to do this.

Answer (score 6):

Without a date column or an auto-increment column, you can't reliably determine the order the records were entered.

The physical order with which rows are stored in the table is non-deterministic.

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer to the OP's question.

Comment: *You can't* is certainly an answer.

Comment: The *ask for clarification* because of limitations - you're assuming it can't be done.

Comment: The OP asked for the rows "that were entered after the one which has been returned". That chronology cannot be established without a date field, autoincrement or similar. I don't see where clarification is needed...?

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer and the comments. Your clarifications have been very helpful. I understand now that I must have the data sorted by some colum in order to be able to achieve what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

If each row has an ID column that is unique and auto incrementing, you could do something like:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE id > (SELECT id FROM table WHERE value = 23.5)
```

Comment: SELECT TOP 3 * FROM table WHERE id > (SELECT  id FROM table WHERE value = 23.5)

Comment: there is no guarantee that the ids will be in order.  This will just base it off id number which isn't necessarily the first x 'above' or 'below' the found row(s).

Comment: Then what do "above" and "below" even mean if not the date they were added to the table? What is the practical purpose of knowing their locations relative to each other in the table?  Maybe I'm misunderstanding the question. An auto-incrementing ID is one way to sort things by date added.  If you're worried about IDs being reset then you could look at adding a time stamp column, instead.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer and the comments. Your clarifications have been very helpful. I understand now that I must have the data sorted by some colum in order to be able to achieve what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you're looking for something like:
`SELECT * FROM table WHERE value <> 23.5`

Comment: No, i actually meant `<>` but I'm not even sure i understood the question correctly. My understanding is that he wants any value that is not equal to `23.5`.

Comment: The OP states they want the row, plus two additional ones.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer and the comments. Actually, I wanted the row returned by the query + the next two rows entered after the one returned by the query. It doesn't necessarily mean that the values of the VALUE column are smaller than the VALUE value  of the returned row.

Answer (score 0):

You can obviously write a program to do that but i am assuming you want a query. What about using a Union. You would also have to create a new column called value_id or something in those lines which is incremented sequentially (probably use a sequence). The idea is that value_id will be incremented for every insert and using that you can write a where clause to return the remaining two values you want.

For example:

Select * from table where value = 23.5 
Union
Select * from table where value_id > 2 limit 2;

Limit 2 because you already got the first value in the first query

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. Your clarification has been helpful. I understand now that an extra column is required.

Answer (score 0):

You need an order if you want to be able to think in terms of "before" and "after".

Assuming you have one you can use ROW_NUMBER() (see more here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) and do something like:

```
With MyTable
(select row_number() over (order by key) as n, key, name, value
from table)

select key, name, value
from MyTable
where n >= (select n from MyTable where value = 23.5)
```